# If $M$ is an $R$-module, how can I show that the Eilenberg-Maclane spectrum $HM$ is an $HR$-module spectrum

Tags: algebraic-topology, stable-homotopy-theory, eilenberg-maclane-spaces, spectra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity, and let $M$ be an $R$-module. I want to show that the Eilenberg-Maclane spectrum $HM$ is an $HR$-module spectrum. Specifically, I want to know how to construct the action of $HR$ on $HM$: $$HR \wedge HM \to HM$$
Here's something related which I believe I understand (please let me know if this is incorrect). Let $S$ be a commutative ring with identity. If we have an action of $S$ on $M$, $$f:S \to End(M)$$ $$x \mapsto f_x$$ then, by applying $H$ to each $f_x$, we get the maps $$Hf_x : HM \to HM$$ Hence, we get an action of $S$ on $HM$. But doing the same thing with the action of $R$ on $M$ clearly doesn't show that $HM$ is an $HR$-module spectrum. I'd appreciate any help you all can give.

Comment: Maybe look [here](https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/~schwede/orthspec.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for this. There is a section which refers directly to my question, but it invokes orthogonal spectra. I'll have to take some time to parse through that since I've never encountered them before. It seems to me that there should be a simpler construction that doesn't involve the structure of orthogonal spectra though.

Comment: What are you familiar with? Symmetric spectra? Sequential?

Comment: I'm familiar with sequential spectra, and I've learned a bit about Spectra as a model category. Originally when I asked this question, I assumed there would be some sort of category theoretic way of constructing the action map I'm looking for.

Comment: Look at Example 5.28. It shows how the EM spectrum is a lax symmetrical monoidal functor from $(\text{Ab},\otimes)$ (abelian groups) into $(\mathcal S,\wedge)$ (symmetric spectra with smash product). In particular, the multiplication $A\times M\rightarrow M$ is equivalent to a group homomorphism $$A\otimes M\rightarrow M$$and so, applying $H$, you get $$HA\wedge HM\rightarrow H(A\otimes M)\rightarrow HM$$

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for! Thank you so much. If you make your comment into an answer, I'd be happy to mark this as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/schwede/SymSpec-v3.pdf) you can find the definition of $HA$ for symmetric spectra (Example 1.14), the construction of the smash product $\wedge$ on the category $\mathcal S^\Sigma$ of symmetric spectra (Section I.5) and that $H$ defines a lax symmetric monoidal functor $$(\mathbf{Ab},\otimes)\rightarrow(\mathcal S^\Sigma,\wedge)$$
(Example 5.28). An $A$-module structure on $M$ is a group homomorphism $A\otimes M\rightarrow M$, so by applying $H$ we get the $HA$-module structure on $HM$ $$HA\wedge HM\rightarrow H(A\otimes M)\rightarrow HM$$